# How to filter context in Rally sdk 2.0?

Tags: rally

I'm playing with the sdk 2.0. I downloaded the examples, in particular I am referring to the "Grid" example. I want to only show results based on a certain workspace (or project...I can't get either to work.)

This is my entire app. I'm trying to set the context on the storeConfig as below. It doesn't work. Is my syntax wrong? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the purpose of this config setting?

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
        type: 'UserStory',
        success: function(model) {
            this.grid = this.add({
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                model: model,
                columnCfgs: [
                    'ScheduleState',
                    'FormattedID',
                    'Name',
                    'Owner',
                    'Project',
                    'Workspace'
                ],
                storeConfig: {
                    context: {
                        workspace: 'Test'
                    },
                    filters: [
                        {
                            property: 'ScheduleState',
                            operator: '=',
                            value: 'Defined'
                        }
                    ]                       
                }
            });
        },
        scope: this
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it right, but the value needs to be the ref of the workspace, not the name:

```
context: {
    workspace: '/workspace/12345' //12345 is the workspace oid
}
```

From inside an app the current context is always available via an accessor and can easily be passed into storeConfigs and other component configs like so:

```
context: this.getContext().getDataContext()
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the workspace oid from the webservice api and set it like you said. However its still returning the same project (from a different workspace.) I see the (wrong) project oid in the querystring. Do I need to set the project AND the workspace to get it to work for debug? There is a particular test project I want to use for debugging, that is my goal here.

Comment: Ah.  Yes the default behavior currently is to merge whatever context you pass in with the global one.  So any values you don't specify will come from the global and in WSAPI project trumps the workspace.  We are going to do some work in this area for GA to make it more consistent and logical.

Comment: Got it working thanks man. I think the 2.0 API doc is a little confusing in that the WsapiDataStore Context config jsut says "the ref of the workspace to scope to". Some examples would be really helpful. I am brand new to Rally sdk so this may have been obvious to experienced users but I found it very confusing. I had to do workspace: '/workspace/9999', project: '/project/8888888' to get it to filter to project.

Comment: I have some other questions i'll be posting if you can help me answer them I be happy to give you upvotes and mark answers. Thanks again.

Comment: Great.  Hopefully this will help others as well.  We know the whole context thing is confusing right now and that we are lacking good examples.  We plan on fixing that before the 2.0 GA.